# Get random number between two doubles

Tags: excel, vba

How to generate random number between 35.9 and 37.2?

Seems like I can generate Integer like this:

```
Int ((37-35+1) * Rnd + 35)
```

But how to do the same with doubles and get double value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me :

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()
Dim r As Double
Randomize
r = (35.9 - 37.2) * Rnd + 37.2
End Sub
```

[image: 1000 Values Test]

Comment: Don't forget to use the [Randomize statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) to initialize the random number generator or you won't get real random numbers.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: They still won't be real (or true). An extended method is needed for that - see, for example, my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).

Comment: @Gustav True, but without `Randomize` they are even more predictable.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ, I add your suggestion to the answer for more visibility, I didn't knew about this feature !

Comment: **35.9** or **39.5** ??

Comment: Oh ! @Gary'sStudent you're right, it doesn't work fine like this ! When I replace "+1" by "+0.01" it works fine but I don't understand why for now... I mean "+0.001" works well too, so I don't know what to use yet, I will look for...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`CDbl(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(359, 372) / 10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Dim mRand As Double
mRand = 35.9 + Rnd * 1.3
```

(1.3 because 37.2-35.9 = 1.3)
Or between 2 values a and b (b>a) :

```
Dim mRand As Double, a As Double, b As Double
mRand = a + Rnd * (b-a)
```